# How to put derivative of composition in Jacobian matrix?

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, function-and-relation-composition

Here are two functions:
$f\left(u,v\right)=u^{2}+3v^{2}$

$g\left(x,y\right)=\begin{pmatrix} e^{x}\cos y  \\ e^{x}\sin y \end{pmatrix}  $

I need to make Jacobian matrix of $f\circ g$. I found derivative of their composition:

$\frac{d\left(f\circ g\right) }{d\left(x,y\right) }=2e^{2x}\cos^{2}{y}+4e^{2x}\sin{y}\cos{y}+6e^{2x}sin^{2}{y}    $

How do I put that in Jacobian matrix?

Comment: What is $\frac{d(f\circ g)}{d(x,y)}$? Try to understand your lesson before getting stuck in exercises.

Comment: If I understood it I wouldnt post here.

Comment: In this case you should  post a question about what you didn't understand in the lesson ;)

Answer (score 3):

Using the chain rule instead:
\begin{align*}D(f\circ g)(x,y)& =\color{red}{Df(g(x,y))}\cdot\color{blue}{ Dg(x,y)}\\
& = \color{red}{\begin{pmatrix} 2u&6v \end{pmatrix}\circ(g(x,y))}\cdot \color{blue}{ \begin{pmatrix}e^x\cos y & -e^x\sin y \\ e^x\sin y & e^x\cos y\end{pmatrix}}\\
& =\color{red}{ \begin{pmatrix} 2e^x\cos y&6e^x\sin y \end{pmatrix}}\cdot \color{blue}{  \begin{pmatrix}e^x\cos y & -e^x\sin y \\ e^x\sin y & e^x\cos y\end{pmatrix}}\\
\phantom{asd} \\
& = \begin{pmatrix}2e^{2x}\cos^2y + 6e^{2x}\sin^2y & -2e^{2x}\cos y \sin y + 6e^{2x}\sin y\cos y \end{pmatrix}\\
\phantom{asd} \\
& = 2e^{2x}\begin{pmatrix}1 + 2\sin^2y & 2\sin y\cos y \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

Comment: But how to put it in matrix? Or the last step is all?

Comment: The last line is indeed a $1\times 2$ matrix. Just as in @Bye-World's answer

Comment: @AnaMatijanovic You should get the same matrix whether you use the chain rule or do the composition first and then evaluate the derivative.  It'll be instructive to do them both (without looking at b00n's answer) and see if you get the same thing.

Comment: Can you explaint two last steps, how did you get 1+2sin^2y ?

Comment: I just played around with the trigonometric identity $\sin^2 y+\cos^2 y=1$

Comment: Ok. I understand. Thank you both!

Answer (score 2):

$$(f\circ g)(x,y) = h(x,y) = e^{2x}\cos^2(y)+3e^{2x}\sin^2(y)$$  Now just build the Jacobian matrix (AKA gradient because $h$ is a scalar-valued function) like normal:  $$\pmatrix{\frac{\partial h}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial h}{\partial y}}$$